# Search and replace HTML code on multiple pages

Tags: content-search, html

I have an old image map that appears on 500+ pages. I would like to delete it and replace it with inline SVG. I know you can search and replace text, but is there a way to search and replace code on multiple pages? Our developers tell me Sitecore does not have that functionality, so editing the HTML is on a per-page basis. Is that true? I do not want to edit 500 pages by hand.

The image map HTML is stored in a RichText field.

As a last resort, if Sitecore does not allow search and replace of HTML, can I download the HTML, edit it, and then upload and overwrite the old pages? I am a content admin/content author, not a developer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you explain in details where is the image map stored now (e.g. if that's a rich text field somewhere there) and what is expected new content?

Comment: The code for the image map is in the rich text editor. The code was copied and pasted by using the HTML view within the RTE. I would like to replace the image map with an inline SVG version of the image. Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use for such a case Sitecore Powershell Extension.

**Pls make a backup package of your items before you run the script.**

Your script will be something like :

```
#get root item
$root = gi master:// -id "{D64DCEAD-7154-4444-BAAC-B20288A9C5DE}"

# get all fields with are richtext 
$items = $root | ls -r | %{$item = $_; $_.Fields  | ?{$_.TypeKey -eq "rich text"} }
$items.Count
foreach($i in $items){
    
    Write-Host "Item Path" $i.Item.Paths.FullPath
    
    if($temp){
        clear-variable("temp")
    }
    if($replaced){
        clear-variable("replaced")
    }

    $replaced = $i.Value -replace 'texttobereplaced', 'newText'
    $temp = $i.Item
    $temp.Editing.BeginEdit()
    $temp.Fields[$i.Name].Value = $replaced
    $temp.Editing.EndEdit()
}
```